# Cross-validation of TPS and kriging outputs from the fields package in R

Tags: r, interpolation, kriging, validation, thin-plate-splines

I am looking for existing package or functions that will allow me to cross-validate multiple outputs of Thin plate spline (TPS) and Kriging from the `fields` package.

Does anyone know of any available package or function in `R` that would do this?

Comment: Well, what type of cross validation? Are you wanting to assess the observed vs predicted (eg., RMSE), perform an n-fold cross-validation or obtain a measure of uncertainty akin to a conditional simulation? Please be specific and detailed in your questions as well as indicating what you have already tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just after a metric of performance, this is a fairly straight forward type of analysis to specify. 1) specify a model, 2) predict the model(s) at the data, 3) apply an accuracy/performance metric based on observed vs. predicted. We can step through the process thus (note; this is a dummy example so, ignore the REML errors):

First lets specify Kriging and Thin Plate Spline models.

```
library(fields)
dat <- data.frame(ozone[["x"]], y=ozone[["y"]])
dat <- rbind( dat, data.frame(East.West=jitter(dat$East.West), 
              North.South=jitter(dat$North.South),
              y=jitter(dat$y)))

krig.fit <- Krig(dat[,1:2], dat$y, theta=20)  
tps.fit <- Tps(dat[,1:2], dat$y)
```

We then predict the models at the data to create a data.frame of the observed data and predictions for each model.

```
obs.pred <- data.frame(y=dat$y, krig=predict(krig.fit),
                       tps=predict(tps.fit) )
```

We can then write a function for the desired evaluation metric, in this case Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE), and apply it to the observed vs predicted data.

```
# RMSE function 
rmse <- function(x, y) sqrt(mean((x - y)^2, na.rm=TRUE))

# Kriging RMSE
rmse(obs.pred$krig, obs.pred$y) 

# Spline RMSE
rmse(obs.pred$tps, obs.pred$y)
```

If you wanted to implement a data withhold type approach you could use sample in a for loop to accumulate error against iteratively withheld data. This has the advantage of assessing the sensitivity of your models to the data.

```
tps.rmse <- vector()    
n <- 5
  for(i in 1:100) {
    s <- sample(1:dim(dat)[1],n)
    obs <- dat[s,]
    m.dat <- dat[-s,]
    md <- Tps(m.dat[,1:2], m.dat$y) 
    pred <- predict(md)[s]
    tps.rmse <- append(tps.rmse, rmse(pred,obs$y))
}
summary( tps.rmse )
```